# AngularJS: should I choose what to print in the view or the controller?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

I have a user info view where I have a table with some user data, which I get asynchronously from the backend. I don't want to print every field of this object.

What's the better practice, to pick the data directly in the template or to generate an object in the controller and then use an ngRepeat in the template?

If I wanted to do more complex stuff, like printing the user groups as an html list, which would be the better option then?

**Example 1: Pick data in template**

```
// controller.js
backendApi.userInfo($stateParams.user)
.then(function (user){
    vm.user = user;
});
```

```
<!-- view.html -->
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">ID</th>
        <td class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">{{vm.user.id}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Name</th>
        <td class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">{{vm.user.name}} {{vm.user.surname}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Status</th>
        <td class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">{{vm.userEnabledString(vm.user)}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">Groups</th>
        <td class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">{{vm.user.groups.join(", ")}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Example 2: Pick data in controller and use ngRepeat in the view.**

```
// controller.js
backendApi.userInfo($stateParams.user)
.then(function (user){
    // user has more fields that I don't need to print.
    vm.user = {
        "ID": user.id,
        "Name": user.name + " " + user.surname,
        "Status" : userEnabledString(user),
        "Groups": user.groups.join(", ")
    }
});
```

```
<!-- view.html -->
<table class="table table-condensed">
    <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.user">
        <th class="col-xs-2 col-md-1">{{key}}</th>
        <td class="col-xs-10 col-md-11">{{value}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The function `userEnabledString` prints a textual representation of a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Why don`t you use existing Angular control instate of re-engineering unless it does not suffice your needs.

Please refer below control, it easy to use.

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-grid/

Comment: It seems to be a bit overkill for my needs and doesn't seem to be easy to style. They seem to use the approach to set the data in the controller instead of the view, though.